# When the endomorphism ring of the injective envelope of any simple module is division ring?

Tags: noncommutative-rings

I have a question. I will be thank you if you give me some hints.
This is the question:

**Let $R$ be a ring and for any simple R-module T, we have End(E(T)) is isomorphic to End(T)  which is a division ring. Does we conclude that every simple R-module is injective**

*(in fact I proved that in this case, every simple R-module is injective (i.e., R is right V-ring) if and only if for any simple R-module T, Hom_{R}(E(T),T) is nonzero).*

Note that E(T) means the **injective envelope** of T,
End(T) means **the endomorphism ring of T**.

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No thats wrong. Take the path algebra over a field with two points with one arrow connecting them (which is isomorphic to the ring of upper triangular 2x2 matrices with field entries). Then every indecomposable module has endomorphism ring isomorphic to the field but not every simple modules is injective.

Note that this algebra $A$ has three indecomposable modules (fix two primitive orthogonal idempotents $e_i$ with $1=e_1+e_2$):
$e_1 A$, $e_2 A$ and $e_1 A/e_1 J^1$ when $J$ denotes the Jacobson radical of $A$.

The endomorphism rings of those modules are isomorphic to $e_1 A e_1 $ or $e_2 A e_2$ which are both 1-dimensional. But the module $e_2 A$ is simple and projective but not injective.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer although I see this message so late. Can you  give me a reference which shows that " over a upper triangular matrix ring R, the endomorphism ring of any indecomposable module is isomorphic to the field."

Comment: @NajmehDehghani This is true for any hereditary representation-finite algebra over a field. A reference for this is the book of Assem, Skowronski and Simson. But the argument here is easy, Ill edit my answer.